# NuxtJS ignore webpack/chokidar watchers for specific file or folder

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js, chokidar

I'm using NuxtJS' serverMiddleware for logging. It works on every route.

```js
import { logger } from './utils/logger';
module.exports = function(req, res, next){
    logger.info('log.js');
    next();
}
```

It works fine, but when im working on dev environment, whenever I navigate some page, it logs some data, Nuxt dev server logs to console: **Updated logs/server.log** and then rebuilds dev server.

I need to extract them from watching list.

I've configured watchers property on nuxt.config.js ( according to this page: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-watchers) :

```
watchers: {
    chokidar: {
      ignored: '/logs/server.log'
    },
    webpack: {
      ignored: '/logs/server.log'
    }
  },
```

but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Thank you for your interest!

**Edit**

I've tried adding files to **.nuxtignore** file. But it doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `.nuxtignore` file and add your file to it. I think this will help ignoring it all the way down.

More info here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-ignore#nuxtignore

UPDATE: this solution may be quite better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74052866/8816585

Comment: I tried this also, it's not working as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation of the configuration-watcher you will find a link to the documentation and syntax needed by chokidar.ignored and webpack.ignored. (Basically use a regexp for a partial match on the path.)

THis should work:

```
watchers: {
    chokidar: { ignored: /logs\/server.log/ },
    webpack: { ignored: /logs\/server.log/ } },
```