# Unable to ignore folders in nuxtjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a problem with **nuxt ignore** to exclude some folders from being watched especially during development. I have searched the internet and the solutions don't seem to work for me.

My `.nuxtignore` file

```
.idea/
```

And the ignore property in `nuxt.config.js`

```
ignore: [
  '**/*.test.*',
  'node_modules/*',
  '**/.idea/*',
  '**/.nuxt/*',
  '**/.*ignore',
],
```

I have also tried using the options independently, initially tried `.idea/*` in both files, still doesn't work, I get output like this in console:

```
↻ Updated .idea/workspace.xml                                                                                                                             16:36:04

✔ Client
  Compiled successfully in 7.20s

No issues found.
```

Is there anything am missing here?

Comment: Hi, did you tried that one? https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/6326#issuecomment-1009037909

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of configuration makes that the `pages` directory is not watched.

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
export default {
  watchers: {
    webpack: {
      ignored: /(pages)/,
    },
  },
}
```

As mentioned here: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/6326#issuecomment-1009037909

Comment: Hi, I had given up on this since none of the solutions worked until today when I checked this question again through notifications, this solution might actually work, I just implemented it and still testing to see if it will really work, once its all good, will mark this as accepted, and thanks btw

Comment: @lulliezy sounds perfect! Keep me updated if you have any success.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: my response below is for Nuxt3/vite so not specific to the original question, but sharing anyway as this was one of the results that came up in my search for trying to resolve the problem I had*

None of the other answers here worked for me. What finally did was adding an `ignore` array [as per the docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config#ignore) to the nuxt.config.ts file. I was getting typescript errors when using some of the other solutions here.

For reference currently running
Nuxi 3.0.0-rc.12
Nuxt 3.0.0-rc.12 with Nitro 0.6.1

```
// nuxt.config.ts:
...
ignore: [
  "path/to/ignore/**"
],
...
```

Comment: The answer was targeting Webpack (for Nuxt2 mostly), you're using Vite in your case so it's a different configuration indeed. Still, don't use an RC version, use the stable `v3.0` version.

Comment: Indeed, just haven't gotten around to the upgrade. Will be launching the site soon though so that'll be one of the housekeeping items to sort. Thanks 

Comment: Ignore also targets builds, I don't think this is the same that the OP is asking for.